# React native app (expo) has extra top-padding only in production

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

In my app, I've created a component that wraps my main screen content, so when the menu button is clicked, the screen content is animated and slides to the side nicely.

My issue is that the main home content is laid perfectly fine on development but on production, the top padding seems to double?

This is my component SlideMenuContainer

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Animated, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

const SlideMenuContainer = ({
  toTheLeft,
  menu,
  page,
}: {
  toTheLeft?: boolean;
  menu: JSX.Element;
  page: (showMenu: boolean, toggleMenu: () => void) => JSX.Element;
}) => {
  // To get the current Status of menu ...
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

  // Animated Properties...
  const offsetValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  // Scale Intially must be One...
  const scaleValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    Animated.timing(scaleValue, {
      toValue: showMenu ? 1 : 0.88,
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();

    Animated.timing(offsetValue, {
      toValue: showMenu ? 0 : toTheLeft ? -240 : 240,
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();

    setShowMenu(!showMenu);
  };

  return (
    <View className="relative h-full max-h-full bg-white">
        <View className={[toTheLeft ? "self-end" : "self-start"].join(" ")}>
          {menu}
        </View>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            flexGrow: 1,
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            borderRadius: showMenu ? 15 : 0,
            overflow: "hidden",
            transform: [{ scale: scaleValue }, { translateX: offsetValue }],
          }}
        >
          <View
            className="flex-1"

          >
            <Animated.View
              className="flex-1 bg-lightest transition-all"
              style={{ 
                paddingTop: showMenu ? 0 : Constants.statusBarHeight
               }}
            >
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => showMenu && toggleMenu()}
                activeOpacity={showMenu ? 0.5 : 1}
                className="relative flex-grow"
              >
                {showMenu && (
                  <View className="absolute top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 bg-gray-900/30 z-10" />
                )}
                {page(showMenu, toggleMenu)}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
          </View>
        </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

And I simply use it like this:

```
<SlideMenuContainer
  menu={<HomeDrawerMenu />}
  page={(showMenu, toggleMenu) => (
    <HomeScreenContent
      showMenu={showMenu}
      toggleMenu={toggleMenu}
      areCompletedVisible={areCompletedVisible}
    />
  )}
/>
```

I believe the issue is with this line:

```
paddingTop: showMenu ? 0 : Constants.statusBarHeight
```

But I'm not sure why it only happens in production or how to fix it.

I'm attaching two screenshots showing the issue, one is development and one is production

Development:
https://imageupload.io/aMTBTD8hwjWSv5O

Production:
https://imageupload.io/PrV53AUir2rU10I

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it only appeared in production too.

Adding this in App.tsx solved it for me:

```
Platform.OS === "android" && StatusBar.setBackgroundColor("transparent");
Platform.OS === "android" && StatusBar.setTranslucent(true);
```